# What do I press to autocomplete the "-------" in console.log() and add a duplicate line?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Starting at 2:15 in the below vscode tutorial video, he types "console.log(", then I am assuming he presses a button that autocomplete the entry to "console.log("------------------"); which duplicates below.

When I type "console.log(" no autocomplete options appear. Additionally, even if I duplicate his code manually as below:

```
console.log("-------------------");
console.log("Rise & Shine!");
console.log("Ready for a new day!");
console.log("-------------------");
```

And press F5, a new window pops open titled "[Extension Development Host] settings.json - Visual Studio Code and returns the following code:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-s71n0dHUk&t=200s

Extensions installed:
JavaSCript (ES6) code snippets
Javascript Debugger
Code Runner
json
npm intellisense

Comment: I think he had the `-------------------` in the clipboard and pressed ⌘+V / Ctrl+V to paste it, and then he pressed ⌥+Shift+↓ / Alt+Shift+↓ to duplicate the line downwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can press option+shift+downarrow to copy a line below (alt+shift+arrow on windows)

To launch with F5, you need node.js installed on your system, with the corresponding extension in vs code.

Comment: Thank you, this worked when I used numpad down arrow to duplicate below. I am still having the issue with F5 opening a new window and returning the above code instead of the debug console returning "Rise & Shine!"', "Ready for a new day!" like in the video.

Comment: edited answer above